# Determine portion of font rendered to left of black box?

Tags: c#, .net, apache-flex, fonts, tlf

I have a font - 'Saginaw' that when renders has some portion of the glyph to the 'left' of the starting position/box:

[Picture here]
http://   i.imgur.com/1lP3C.png

The above snip is of the font in Photoshop.. I did a 'select all' to show the black box..

I'm trying to figure out what that offset/value is [portion of the W rendered on the left outside the box]

Thus far, I've been delving through [System.Windows.Media.GlyphTypeFace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphtypeface.aspx) which has much interesting goodies, including AdvancedWidths, LeftSideBearings, DistancesFromHorizontalBaselienToBlackBottom, etc.

However, I don't quite grok how to apply the values I'm seeing from the font to calculate a value that corresponds to that offset.

In the end, I'm trying to take this font metadata and render the font/text up in a Flex RichEditableTextArea, where the curvy left hand side of the font is getting cut off:

[Picture Here]
http://   i.imgur.com/Hjm7V.png

I'd not seen anything yet in the Flex TLF that lets me peer at that part of the Font data.

[I'm sure it's probably just hiding from me]

Via experimentation I'd seen I can set the padding in the RichEditableTextArea to shift the font over, then it renders the 'cut off' portion inside itself.

I was hoping to find the amount of the font/glyph 'left shift'; then apply appropriate padding to compensate.

[Alternately, if someone knows how to force the RichEditableTextArea to render that portion that is getting cut off, that would work as well!]

If anyone has any insight I would be deeply grateful!

--Erik

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the LeftSideBearings doesn't cover this?

> **Property Value**
>
> Type:
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary An IDictionary
>   object that contains key/value pairs
>   that represent distance information
>   for the glyphs. The key is a UInt16
>   that identifies the glyph index. The
>   value is a Double that represents the
>   distance.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The LeftSideBearings
>   value is positive when the left edge
>   of the black box is within the
>   alignment rectangle defined by the
>   advance width and font cell height.
>
> The LeftSideBearings value is negative
>   when the left edge of the black box
>   overhangs the alignment rectangle.

This should give you the number you need as a negative.

Comment: I see the values there, I'm unsure how to use the data.. Say for 'w':  Key 87 Char:W size: -0.005     I've not yet discovered how to use that value... is it a percentage of em size?  some percentage of advance width?

Comment: I believe that it is the percentage of the em-size.